# How to convert this program from C++ to C?

Tags: c++, c, file-io, readfile

I need to convert this part of my program from C++ to C, can you please help me with that?

```
float ** OpenRotGrid_H(float **grid, unsigned int &nl, unsigned int & nc, bool &ok){
    ifstream fs;
    string line, num;
    unsigned int l(0),c(0),i(0),ncmax(0);

    fs.open("CarmY.txt");
    if (!fs) {
        //std::cout<<"Error: the Error file 'CarmY.txt' cannot be open\n\n";
        ok=false;
    }
    else{
        //size of the file
        getline(fs,line);
        ncmax= line.size()/MAXFLOAT;
        nl++;
        while(getline(fs,line)){
            nl++;
        }
        fs.clear();

        //Read CarmY values ( = grid)
        grid = initialize(nl,ncmax);
        fs.seekg(0,ios::beg); //initial position in the file

        while(getline(fs,line)){
            i=0;
            c=0;
            while(i<line.length()){
                while(i<line.length() && line[i]!='\t'){
                    num.push_back(line[i]);
                    i++;
                }
                grid[l][c]=(float) atof(num.c_str());
                c++;
                num.clear();
                if(i<line.length() && line[i]!='\n') i++;
            }
            l++;
        }
        nc=c;
        fs.close();
    }
    return grid;
}

int main(){

unsigned int nl=0 , nc=0 , nangle=0, nrot=0;
float **grid;
bool ok;

grid=initialize(nangle, nrot);
OpenRotGrid_H(grid, nl, nc, ok);


return 0;

}
```

The file "C-arm" has some rows of numbers with different lengths , this program open this file and take each number and write it in the grid.

I don't know for example what can i use instead of `getline(fs,line)` , `fs.seekg` and ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, hitting the obvious candidates:

- there are no references (such as `unsigned int &nl`) in C so you'll need to pass pointers and change the underlying data by dereferencing those pointers.
- you can just use `int` instead of `bool`.
- there are no `ifstream` objects in C, , use the `fopen` call to open the file instead.
- `getline` can be turned into `fgets`.
- you can use `fseek` instead of `seekg`.
- there are no intelligent strings in C, you'll need to manage them at a slightly lower level (character arrays).
- `length` can be replaced with `strlen`.

There's almost certainly some other little niggles but that should be a good start.

Comment: C99 provides stdbool.h which may be used for boolean values. getline is also available in C albeit with a different syntax.

Comment: @FUZxxl, yes, though I've never had the need to use booleans since the old style ways are perfectly fine for a codger like me :-) However, I think you may be incorrect about getline - it doesn't even appear in C11 (I suspect it's a GNU extension).

Comment: According to my manual they were standartized in POSIX.1-2008

Comment: thanks @paxdiablo, since i am new to C program , this is a big help :)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes If you're programming for Posix, you may assume Posix.